# Ayuda con esta imagen no se ajusta al div

Tags: html, css3

No puedo hacer que esta imagen se acomode este es código css que tengo.
lo selecionado es el codigo html de la parte donde esta la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CSS**

```
.login100-form-title {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: cover;
  padding: 70px 15px 74px 15px;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPQdp.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/evBhY.jpgtexto en negrita

Comment: Cual imagen?  Incluye tambien tu HTML

Comment: gracias por decirme ya mostre la seccion del codigo html donde esta la imagen

Answer (score 0):

tienes un error con la propiedad `background-position`, esta propiedad solamente acepta los valores siguientes: `left, center, right, top, bottom`, y para que la imagen tome el total del ancho del `div`, debes remplazar el valor de contain por cover en la propiedad `background-size`:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Y puedes añadir esto para centrar la imagen:

```
background-position: center;
```

Comment: no funcion se agrando la imagen y no se ve completa